# getting schema for a table

Tags: c#, asp.net

look at this code :

> ```
> public void GetScheme4Table(string tableName)
> {
>     OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\" + DdListDatabases4GettingTables.SelectedValue + ".mdb;Persist Security Info=True");
>     conn.Open();
>     DataTable schemaTable = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,
>                                                      new object[] { null, null, null, tableName });
>     GridViewTablesScheme.DataSource = schemaTable;
>     GridViewTablesScheme.DataBind();
>     conn.Close();  
> }
> ```

There is no rows in the schema data table how I can solve this ?

I want to get schema for my table and show in the gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public DataTable GetScheme4Table(string tableName)
{
    DataTable ret = null;
    IDbCommand command = null;

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\" + DdListDatabases4GettingTables.SelectedValue + ".mdb;Persist Security Info=True"))
    {
        command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [{0}]", tableName);
        using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo))
        {
            ret = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```